# how to reference a cell through vba

Tags: excel, vba, reference

I just wrote some codes which pick up values from one workbook,worksheet and paste them in another workbook, worksheet. Currently it pastes in as values.
Here are some parts of my code:

```
Do Until Cells(i, 9) = "Net Income"
 If Cells(i, 9) = "BONDS INTEREST EARNED" Then
    Bonds_IE = Cells(i + 1, 9)
```

and then with another book activated,

```
Cells(j - 5, 4) = Bonds_IE
```

I want this to show up as a reference to where it pulled the information from.
for Ex:   K:\etc\etc\etc[etc.xlsx] etc!$A$1

I feel like this should be super simple but I am not sure..
Please help :(
Thanks!!

Comment: `Cells` used like this, implicitly refers to whatever the `ActiveSheet` is. Qualify it with a `Worksheet` object instance before you run into other issues.

Answer (score 2):

VBA code does a lot of things implicitly. If we make everything explicit, the problem becomes clearer:

```
Do Until CStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 9).Value) = "Net Income"
 If CStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 9).Value) = "BONDS INTEREST EARNED" Then
    Bonds_IE = CStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 9).Value)
```

Note:

- Implicit string conversions, made explicit with `CStr`. These *will* blow up with a *type mismatch* error if the cell contains an error value. You may want to verify whether `IsError` returns `False` given a cell's value, before doing anything with that value.
- Implicit `ActiveSheet` references. These *will* blow up with run-time error 1004 if you use them against a qualified `Range` call that isn't referring to the active sheet, e.g.:

  ```
  Sheet12.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i + 1, 1)) = 42 'Sheet12 isn't active
  ```
- Implicit *default member* calls. `Cells` returns a `Range` object; its default member points to its `Value`. That's why you can do `Cells(j - 5, 4) = foo` and still have compilable code. Making member calls explicit helps better understand what's *really* going on when you read the code.

[As already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44031596/1188513), `Range.Value` gets/sets the range's *value*. What you want is its `.Formula`.

Comment: I tried changing as .formula
What happens now is instead of referencing the cell like 
='[210303 to 2017 Yearend NEW.xlsm]210303 2017'!$I$199 
which is what i want, it now pulls =A1*I199 which is a formula in that cell

Comment: I'm sorry, what you're looking for is not exactly clear (where's that multiplication coming from? it's nowhere in your post). `.Formula` gets/sets a string that represents the formula that's used to calculate a range's `.Value`. You need to build that string to make it whatever formula you need to have. Or did you mean to make a cell's *value* be another cell's *formula*?

Comment: I have two cells. Cell A1 and Cell B1 which are in two different workbooks. I want cell A1 to be "=CellB1". I just want to refernece cell A to Cell B. Cell B will have its own calculation in that worksheet. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Then you want to "build" CellA1's `Formula` string using `=` followed by CellB1's `Parent.Parent.FullName` (the workbook's path) enclosed in square brackets, followed by `Parent.Name` (the worksheet's name) enclosed in single quotes, followed by an exclamation mark, followed by CellB1's `Address`.

Comment: ^^ But simpler to use `Address(External:=True)`

Comment: @YowE3K *facepalm* yes, yes absolutely!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to reference the `.Formula` of the cell, instead of the default, which is `.Value`.

```
Do Until Cells(i, 9) = "Net Income"
 If Cells(i, 9) = "BONDS INTEREST EARNED" Then
    Bonds_IE = Cells(i + 1, 9).Formula

Cells(j - 5, 4).Formula = Bonds_IE
```

Comment: I tried changing as .formula
What happens now is instead of referencing the cell like 
='[210303 to 2017 Yearend NEW.xlsm]210303 2017'!$I$199 
which is what i want, it now pulls =A1*I199 which is a formula in that cell

Answer (score 1):

Try using the source cell's `Address` to create a `Formula`:

```
Dim Bonds_IE As String
Do Until Cells(i, 9) = "Net Income"
    If Cells(i, 9) = "BONDS INTEREST EARNED" Then
        Bonds_IE = "=" & Cells(i + 1, 9).Address(RowAbsolute:=True, _
                                                 ColumnAbsolute:=True, _
                                                 External:=True)
'...
'...
Cells(j - 5, 4).Formula = Bonds_IE
```

One trick with this though ... `Address(External:=True)` will not include the **path** to the original workbook, so the resultant string needs to be applied as a `Formula` to the other cell **before** the original workbook is closed.  That way, when the original workbook is closed, Excel will automatically update the formula to include the path as well.