# file name vba construction

Tags: vba, excel, filenames

i need help with a file name, debug show some mistake (syntax error) in saving process, that's probably filename construction. 
I'd appreciate some help:

```
 Sub zapiszpdf2()
Dim DATA As String
DATA = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")

    Columns("E:F").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=
   ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "C_a_" & DATA & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard,
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, From:=1, To:=1, OpenAfterPublish:=True, OpenAfterPublish:= _
        True

    Columns("D:G").Select

    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

End Sub
```

---

Found it! An extra "," and double "open after", as you said. I also get rid of "select". Thanks a lot.

```
 Sub zapiszpdf2()
Dim DATA As String
DATA = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")

Columns("E:F").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

 ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
       ActiveWorkbook.Path & "C_a_" & DATA & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, From:=1, To:=1, OpenAfterPublish:=True


Columns("D:G").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
```

End sub

Comment: What's the question? :)

Comment: And what is the error message and on which line?

Comment: You have twice `OpenAfterPublish:=True` in the line with the `ExportAsFixedFormat `

Comment: The usual [avoid Select](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/9439330)

Comment: Next step is avoid [implicit references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44031745/9439330)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, 'OpenAfterPublish:=True' has been written twice and you can just delete one.

```
 Sub zapiszpdf2()
Dim DATA As String
DATA = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")

Columns("E:F").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=
   ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "C_a_" & DATA & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard,
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, From:=1, To:=1, OpenAfterPublish:=True

Columns("D:G").Select

Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

End Sub
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: My bad - i have deleted the second "open after", but there is still syntax error in: ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=
   ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "C_a_" & DATA & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard,
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, From:=1, To:=1, OpenAfterPublish:=True

Answer (score 0):

i see two problems

first you have **OpenAfterPublish:=True** twice, just delete one

and second i thick you are not selecting the "activesheet"

try to put **Sheets("NAME_OF_SHEET").Select** before the export to PDF

thanks